# retrieve .numPages (pyPDF2) in self.setText

Tags: python, pyqt5, pypdf

i can retrieve the page number from pdf with function print but
how do it with self setText ??

when i try :

x = (pdfReader.numPages)

self.ui.aff_page.setText(x)

It didn't work

i need some explanations

here the code:

The main:

```
import sys, os, PyPDF2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from testUI import Ui_MainWindow

class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.show()  

    self.ui.pushButton_fichier.clicked.connect(self.dossier)

def dossier(self):

    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file','C:/Users/le/Desktop/29/ATM','Image files (*.pdf)')[0]
    print (os.path.basename(fname))
    filename = os.path.basename(fname)
    self.ui.aff_nom.setText(filename)


    pdfFileObj = open(fname, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    print(pdfReader.numPages)
    self.ui.aff_page.setText("")
    pdfFileObj.close()




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work?

Comment: `self.ui.aff_page.setText(str(pdfReader.numPages))`, numPages is an integer, you must convert it to string

Comment: thanks  eyllanesc setText (self, QString)

Comment: @eyllanesc Seems your comment was the answer. Do you want to make it an answer?